# Tab stops in windows form in Office VSTO addin don't work

Tags: vb.net, vsto, ms-office, office-addins, ms-project

I'm writing a simple VSTO add-in for Office.  When the user clicks a button a single form appears, and on the form there are some single-line textboxes, some buttons and some labels.  This is all in VB.NET.

Everything works as expected - except I cannot tab between controls on the form.  I have set the TabIndex and TabStop properties (actually, left them at defaults, which look OK).  I've also tried programmatically setting TabIndex and TabStop in the form's Shown handler - but this made no difference.  Changing runtime from .NET 4.5 to 4.6 makes no difference.

The odd thing is that if I use exactly the same form (copy & paste the .vb file) in a Windows Forms App, the tab stops work.  It seems there's something about this VSTO project (or perhaps all VSTO projects) that is stopping tabbing working.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the host application for the VSTO addin is MS Project 2016.

Comment: What is your code? Do you use the `Show` or `ShowDialog` method of the `Form` class?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - I was using Show().  Your comment was absolutely right: using ShowDialog() gets the tabbing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a standalone WinForms application and your Office add-in is the host application (can be MDI or SDI application).

Most probably you need to specify the parent window handle to the `Show` method. The [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) accepts an instance of the [IWin32Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.iwin32window?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) interface which represents the top-level window that will own this form.